# The documented (first) example for R function `constrOptim` seems wrong

Tags: r, optimization, syntax, constraints

Here is a snippet from the first example under `?constrOptim`:

```
# x <= 0.9,  y - x > 0.1
constrOptim(c(.5,0), fr, grr, ui = rbind(c(-1,0), c(1,-1)), ci = c(-0.9,0.1))
```

Using the commented line, shouldn't the `ui` input be:

```
ui = rbind(c(-1,0), c(-1,1))
```